# Update DLL reference

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2012, reference

I wanted to update some DLLs used in my .NET project to the latest version and I've noticed that, if I replace the DLLs on the file system with their new versions, VS 2012 updates the DLL version number in the Properties window.

Is this some new feature of VS 2012? I don't remember seeing it in VS 2010 (I expected it would need more manual handling).

Is this working right, or should I remove and re-add the DLLs manually from the references, just to be sure?

Anyway, my project compiles and runs fine, so I guess it works...

**EDIT:**

I guess it works because the DLLs are not strongly named (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx)?
Perhaps I should re-add them if they were...
Inside the project file I saw it had the old version number, but in the properties window I saw the new one...

Thanks!

Comment: That down-vote means that my question isn't good? Should I ask questions only for code related stuff? What is it? You don't like my (hidden) face or sth?

Comment: You can check my answer related to that type of question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944679/how-to-update-assembly-assembly-references-in-a-web-site/52762061#52762061

Comment: You can check my answer on the same type of question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944679/how-to-update-assembly-assembly-references-in-a-web-site/52762061#52762061

Comment: I had this problem too and I did open/close dll properties window and It reloaded itself.

Comment: Related post - [.NET DLL references/dependency checking utility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8750018/465053)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's better to remove and re-add your references. You said it yourself that the project file was not up-to-date.

I am not sure if there is an add-on for VS that could make updating DLLs easier. If there isn't one, definitely someone should make one. Changing assembly references in large projects is a pain in the @ss.

Comment: How is removing and readding references not a hack? Is there some cleaner way?

Comment: @AndersLindén Well, if you are using NuGet you could update them all at once: http://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html. But for the rest of the cases I haven't found any alternative. The other answer below from Evalds Urtans is something I have never tried. But I don't understand why VS would update the DLL references on project reload.

Answer (score 44):

Easier option to refresh / **reload references** & types DLL (for example **COM interop types**) without re-adding all DLLs one-by-one is to reload all projects that reference it like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortuantely unloading and reloading doesn't appear to work in VS2015 at least (14.0.24720.00 Update 1)

Comment: Right now I tried Unload and Reload of Project with external DLLs, that are not in the same solution. It works.
VS 2015 Version is 14.0.25421.03 Update 3

Comment: Did not work for me in VS2015 using COM references. But removing the COM DLL and re-adding did work.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is - go to 'manage nuget packages' and update all.

Answer (score 1):

Managing references as NuGet packages is significantly easier. You can view which references became out of date and choose which to update.
Downside: if you are not using the standard packages (available via NuGet.org) you have to manage your own NuGet repository.

You can manage your NuGet packages via GUI or console.
[NuGet packages manager GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vF8.png)

Answer (score 0):

better option is to de refrence the dll and refrence again but make sure for safety purpse you keep the backup of your previous dll...